# Assertion error (-215) npoints >= 0 and error while extracting letters from captcha image

Tags: python, opencv

While making a program that extract the letters from the captcha image i am having a error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:741: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'pointSetBoundingRect'
```

After trying alot I came to know that the error is because in my code i am using a image that is producing a matrix which contains negative numbers but actually in pointSetBoundingRect function it assert to have `npoints >= 0` I tried using different images but all produced the same result.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import imutils

img = cv2.imread('cap2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.copyMakeBorder(gray, 8, 8, 8, 8, cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else contours[1]

for contour in contours:
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    print ((x,y,w,h))
```

Please help! How can I make the matrix that is autogenerated from a image to have positive points.
Or please tell me if the error is something else.

Here is the captcha image i am using in above code.

[image: captcha image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In opencv 4.0, `cv2.findContours` return 2 values, [see here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html). So it could be like this

```
 contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```